# can i say "四者択一の問題"?

Tags: set-phrases

Since "二者択一の問題" is *a multiple choice problem with **2** options*, would it be understandable to say:
"三者択一の問題" --> *multiple choice with **3** options*
"四者択一の問題" --> *multiple choice with **4** options*
.....

would it also be a natural thing to say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can fill in any number in `n 者択一`, but it generally sounds too lofty, and the most common way to name it is `n 択`. "Multiple choice problem with *n* options" is often called `n 択問題`.

By the way, "multiple choice problem" itself is 択一問題, 選択問題, or 多肢選択問題.